# Thymeleaf + Spring: How to write "[]" in a template file?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using a text template (i.e. .txt extension templates) where I am writing a line like [/], but when parsing it using Thymeleaf+Spring it's showing error Malformed content: unnamed clsoing element is never opened.
Since [/] is used in a template by thmyeleaf as a closing tag so it's showing this error.

I can obviously give names to "[" and "]" and substitute them. But then I will have to add these names to a lot of properties files.

Thanks

Comment: The link is not working. It's 404 error

Comment: You can try to surround your code with a CDATA block. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_cdatasection.asp should help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be written as follows:

```
[# th:text="'[/]'"/]
```